# When exactly did everyone figure out about Lucy?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

So I've been playing through the Assassins Creed series recently, all for the first time.

Spoilers below:

> I managed to figure out that Lucy was a templar, because of what Juno says when she forces Desmond to stab her (plus, it was also a lucky guess). However, as far as I can remember, the characters never figured this out.
>  But, then, in Assassins Creed III, they just casually mention that she had betrayed them and was a Templar. When did they figure this out? I assume that it'd have to be in Revelations, but I don't remember that happening (or really, much of anything with any present-day characters but Desmond).
>  Did I just completely miss something? Or did they just figure it out offscreen based on what Juno said (though, then again, they couldn't hear her, and Desmond went into a coma right after, so I guess not).

Comment: spoiler tags, yo! Not everyone has played through the series.

Comment: I intentionally left out the spoiler from the title. If someone hasn't played it, they shouldn't click on this question. And if it's an accident, it's not like spoiler tags would stop them anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate from another site http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31650/what-happened-to-lucy-after-the-end-of-assassins-creed-brotherhood

Comment: my question which was flagged as duplicate http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59054/when-was-it-revealed-that-lucy-was-a-sleeper-agent

Comment: Oh, hey, thank you Memor-X, I couldn't figure out what was wrong with the tags. That helps.

Comment: I guess I'd count it as a duplicate. The point of the question is different - one is asking what happened, but I already knew what happened and simply wanted to know where it was explained, but that also gets brought up in the answers for the other, so...

Comment: @KevinMills for some reason line breaks turn them into a quote box and you can just have a blank >! line, i used `<br>` at the end each line (it'll only show this if you edit the question)

Comment: @KevinMills reason why i posted up my question, i asked the same thing on Scifi and it was flagged as duplicate, of cause someone could use my links to post an answer for free rep

Comment: If they're looking at the question, then chances are good they know what's happening.  There's no need for a spoiler warning in the title.  Besides, that breaks the title in the first place.

Comment: @KevinMills can you consider reviewing and accepting my answer to help others who might have the same question

Comment: @KevinMills my best argument is that WHEN is in AC: Revelations. The exact moment is never referenced. It's just a DLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in Assassin's Creed Revelations they gave us a DLC called **The Lost Archive**

> **The Lost Archive** is a downloadable content addition for Assassin's
>   Creed: Revelations, with gameplay similar to the Desmond's Journey
>   sequences. It follows the life of Clay Kaczmarek, also known as
>   Subject 16 of the Animus Project.

In this DLC we also find that

**[SPOILER]**

> Lucy was all along a Templar working for Vidic. And you have access to interesting dialog between them and everything. I was jaw dropped when I played it.

Basically if you want more defined answers by playing the game I would highly recommend playing Revelations and this DLC.

More Info on **The Lost Archive** [here](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Archive).